# @UniqueEntity does not work for me with a simple string property

Tags: symfony, doctrine, unique-constraint

I have a "Company" entity with three fields : id, name and slug. The name is unique.

When I attempt to create a new Company with a name already used I get the following error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO companies (name, slug) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["test", "test-1"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'UNIQ_8244AA3A5E237E06'
```

I don't know why, but the @UniqueEntity does not show my error message. I also tried to put this line : @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"}, groups={"company"})

Here is the code of the class :

```
<?php
namespace Project\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="companies")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"}, message="form.error.name.unique")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="form.error.name.not_blank");
     * @Assert\Length(min="4", max="50", minMessage="form.error.name.length.min {{ limit }}", maxMessage="form.error.name.length.max {{ limit }}");
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(length=170, unique=true)
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="company")
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $users;
}
```

Comment: Clear cache, clear APC cache and try to add this entity again

Comment: Can you provide some more code? (fragments of template where you render the form and controller)

Comment: Did you delete the previously created index key from your table before updating your schema?

Comment: You also need to define your unique constraint index name by changing the `@ORM\Table(...)` to `@ORM\Table(name="companies", uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="New_Unique_Indxes_Name", columns={"name"})})`

Comment: This might be implied in your question, but are you actually validating the entity in your controller?

Comment: The constraint only prevent duplicate names in the db not 'printing' message somewhere. use other technic to show to the user that the name already exists (mybe some ajx calls .. )

Comment: Timmz, I've put the form_errors() im my template. Now the problem is solved. I've delete my index key and update my schema and it worked. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test this 3 possibilities and try to get the default message? (But it seems that you already tried the third one. Maybe luck with the others)
(Btw, you can not set a groups option in the UniqueEntity annotation)

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"})
 */
class User
{
     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", unique=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works for me:
`@UniqueEntity("name", message="form.error.name.unique")`